# When is a 2d dynamical system conservative?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

A dynamical system
\begin{equation}
\dot x = f(x,y) \quad\quad \dot y = g(x,y)
\end{equation}
has a conserved quantity $E$ if
\begin{equation}
\frac{dE}{dt} = \frac{\partial E}{\partial x}\dot x + \frac{\partial E}{\partial y}\dot y = 0
\end{equation}
I'm trying to understand the conditions on $f$ and $g$ for such an $E$ to exist.

My understanding is that this depends on the equation
\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{g(x,y)}{f(x,y)}
\end{equation}
being exact, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
\end{equation}
in which case the equation can be integrated to $E$. Thus, for instance, for the simple harmonic oscillator
\begin{equation}
\dot x = y \quad\quad \dot y = -\omega^2x
\end{equation}
we have
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = 0 = -\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
\end{equation}
So a conserved quantity exists, obtained from
\begin{equation}
y\frac{dy}{dx} + \omega^2x = 0
\end{equation}
which integrates to the usual
\begin{equation}
E = \frac12\omega^2x^2+\frac12y^2
\end{equation}
However, this doesn't work for a different example (from [https://services.math.duke.edu/~jtwong/math356-2019/lectures/Dynamics4_cons_lyapunov.pdf](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ejtwong/math356-2019/lectures/Dynamics4_cons_lyapunov.pdf)):
\begin{equation}
\dot x = x(1-y) \quad\quad \dot y = ay(x-1)
\end{equation}
That is,
\begin{equation}
x(1-y)\frac{dy}{dx} + ay(1-x) = 0
\end{equation}
is *not* exact. However, we can multiply through by $1/xy$ to get
\begin{equation}
\frac{1-y}y\frac{dy}{dx} + a\frac{1-x}x = 0
\end{equation}
which *is* exact.

This leads me to think that the condition on $f$ and $g$ for a conserved quantity to exist is that there exists some function $a(x,y)$ such that
\begin{equation}
a(x,y)f(x,y)\frac{dy}{dx} - a(x,y)g(x,y) = 0
\end{equation}
is exact. When will this *not* be the case?

Moreover, in the case of a 2nd order ODE
\begin{equation}
\dot x = y \quad\quad \dot y = g(x,y)
\end{equation}
how does this proposition impose $g(x,y)=g(x)$, which I believe it should?

(Sorry for the length.)

Comment: You are mixing ideas from systems having a first integral and systems being Hamiltonian. That this is not the same you demonstrated in your example. But I'm not sure at the moment where to draw the lines. A separable Hamiltonian with kinetic and potential term gives a conservative system. But is Volterra-Lotka conservative, or does it just have a first integral and thus closed solution curves?